# How to use dynamic variable in smarty template function

Tags: smarty, variable-declaration

I need to use the variable inside the `popup` tag from Smarty.

I can't declare the var on the server because it's dynamic (originating from a loop).

I tried all the different approaches with the assign tag like

```
{assign var=title value="$some_loop_var - sitename!"}
```

or

```
{assign var="myfield" value=$some_loop_var + "btn_licencee_select"}
```

Always the printed variable is empty.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This actually a smarty plugin an not an original smarty function. And i guess you dont have to escape it like you did. You could use `value={"{$some_loop_var}_static_part"}` as well. This should be possible since [Feb. '10, what you could see here](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16808)  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite trivial in the end:

If you use a variable inside a Smarty function you need to "escape" it with backticks:

```
{popup text="`$some_loop_var`_static_part" }
```

Hope this helps anybody else as well. Took me hours to figure this out...